# Behaviour of non-const int pointer on a const int

Tags: pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
       const int sum=100;
        int *p=(int *)&sum;

        *p=101; 


        printf("%d, %d",*p,sum);
        return 0;
}
```

/*

output

101, 101

*/

p points to a constant integer variable, then why/how does *p manage to change the value of sum?

Comment: Try it with different optimization settings. Most likely there is a compiler out there that will print 101, 100 with enough optimizations enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's undefined behavior - it's a bug in the code.  The fact that the code 'appears to work' is meaningless. The compiler is allowed to make it so your program crashes, or it's allowed to let the program do something nonsensical (such as change the value of something that's supposed to be const). Or do something else altogether.  It's meaningless to 'reason' about the behavior, since there is no requirement on the behavior.

Note that if the code is compiled as C++ you'll get an error since C++ won't implicitly cast away `const`.  Hopefully, even when compiled as C you'll get a warning.

Comment: I compiled the code as .cpp and got the following as output: 101, 100  It compiles fine but output is more sane here.

Comment: Note: the (int*) cast wasn't in the code when I commented that C++ wouldn't compile it.  That cast makes the code compile as C++, but the `*p=101;` expression is still undefined behavior. The fact that you got something that makes sense to you still doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please point me to some compiler specs docs which throw light on such undefined behaviour.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.3.7/5 `If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.`.

Comment: And for C++03, 7.1.5.1/4 "The cv-qualifiers":  "Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior".

Answer (score 2):

`p` contains the memory address of the variable `sum`. The syntax `*p` means the actual value of `sum`.

When you say

```
*p=101
```

you're saying: go to the address `p` (which is the address where the variable `sum` is stored) and change the value there. So you're actually changing `sum`.

Comment: That's my point. If sum has been defined as const , then how am I allowed to change it ?

Comment: The const does not protect the memory location. It only protects the variable sum. Const is only checked in compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You can see `const` as a compile-time flag that tells the compiler "I shouldn't modify this variable, tell me if I do." It does not enforce anything on whether you *can* actually modify the variable or not.

And since you *are* modifying that variable through a non-const pointer, the compiler is indeed going to tell you:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:6:16: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

You broke your own promise, the compiler warns you but will let you proceed happily.

Comment: Hi,edited the question to  int *p=(int *)&sum; The warning doesn't show up now.

Comment: @SHOUBHIKBOSE Because you are forcibly casting to `(int*)`, which tells the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing". So no warning.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is undefined, which means that it may produce different outcomes on different compiler implementations, architecture, compiler/optimizer/linker options.

---

For the sake of analysis, here it is:

**(Disclaimer: I don't know compilers. This is just a logical guess at how the compiler may choose to handle this situation, from a naive assembly-language debugger perspective.)**

- When a constant integer is declared, the compiler has the choice of making it addressable or non-addressable.

  - Addressable means that the integer value will actually occupy a memory location, such that:

    - The lifetime will be static.
    - The value might be hard-coded into the binary, or initialized during program startup.
    - It can be accessed with a pointer.
    - It can be accessed from any binary code that knows of its address.
    - It can be placed in either read-only or writable memory section.
    - For everyday CPUs the non-writeability is enforced by memory management unit (MMU). Messing the MMU is <s>messy</s> impossible from user-space, and it is not worth for a mere const integer value.
    - Therefore, it will be placed into writable memory section, for simplicity's sake.
    - If the compiler chooses to place it in non-writable memory, your program will crash (access violation) when it tries to write to the non-writable memory.
    - Setting aside microcontrollers - you would not have asked this question if you were working on microcontrollers.
  - Non-addressable means that it does not occupy a memory address. Instead, every code that references the variable (i.e. use the value of that integer) will receive a r-value, as if you did a find-and-replace to change every instance of `sum` into a literal `100`.

    - In some cases, the compiler **cannot** make the integer non-addressable: if the compiler knows that you're taking the address of it, then surely the compiler knows that it has to put that value in memory. Your code belongs to this case.
    - Yet, with some aggressively-optimizing compiler, it is entirely possible to make it non-addressable: the variable could have been **eliminated** and the `printf` will be turned into `int main() { printf("%s, %s", (b1? "100" : "101"), (b2? "100" : "101")); return 0; }` where `b1` and `b2` will depend on the mood of the compiler.
  - The compiler will sometimes take a split decision - it might do one of those, or even something entirely different:

    - Allocate a memory location, but replace every reference with a constant literal. When this happens, a debugger will tell you the value is zero but any code that uses that location will appear to contain a hard-coded value.
  - Some compiler may be able to detect that the cast causes a undefined behavior and refuse to compile.