# How to get the real address of i from "const int i"

Tags: c++, constants

```
int main()
{
  const int i = 10;
  int *p = (int*) &i;
  *p = 20; 
  printf("%d\n",i);   // 10
  printf("%d\n",*p);  // 20
}
```

Can I get i's real address?
If I want to change the i's value, how can I do it?
Forgive my poor English!

Comment: What result do you get from this code?

Comment: Why do you want to change the value of a _constant_? Use normal variables if you want to change values.

Comment: I'm afraid `i` is not real, it's imaginary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Behaviour of non-const int pointer on a const int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698048/behaviour-of-non-const-int-pointer-on-a-const-int)

Comment: @Bo Persson this is in c, c++ is different.

Comment: @linw - No, there is no difference between the languages when trying to change the value of a constant. A constant is, eh, *constant*.

Answer (score 8):

> Can I get i's real address?

Yes:

```
const int* p = &i;
...
printf("%p\n", p);
```

> If I want to change the i's value, how can I do it?

You better not, it is *undefined behaviour*. After all, `const` means "can't be changed" isn't it? If you do want to change it for whatever reason, it shouldn't be declared a `const`, period.

On some platforms, const data is put into a different, read-only memory segment, and attempting to write to such places causes a segfault. Also, many compilers replace references to const variables with their literal value, and - as seems to be in your case - attempts to take the address of these may instead create a temporary variable with a copy of the original value. So you can only change the temporary value, not the original.

Comment: To print address, the format specifier should be `%p`, not `%x`, as the number of bytes to be represented by `%x` may not be equal to `sizeof(pointer)`.

Answer (score 4):

You get the "real" address exactly as you've done with `&i`.

As `i` is a `const` qualified object you *cannot* change its value once it has been initialized.

It is a bad idea to cast the result of that expression to a pointer to a modifiable `int` because it allows you to write `*p = 20;` which causes *undefined behavior* as it is an attempt to modify that value of a `const` object.

Comment: Thank you!In c is a "real" address, but c++ is not.@Charles Bailey

Comment: What do you mean be a "real" address? Why don't you think that `&i` is a "real" address?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
printf("%p\n",p);
```

`%p` is intended to format the pointer value.

`i`'s value cannot be changed and may result in various bugs (or do nothing at all.)